# Infinite scroll + tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, tooltip

estoy tratando de implementar una página con [infinite scroll](https://infinite-scroll.com/) y añadir [tooltips](https://popper.js.org/tooltip-examples.html) a algunos items. Infinite scroll funciona bien, pero los tooltips sólo aparecen en la primera página, antes de añadir nuevos items con el scroll. Este es el ejemplo:

https://stage.superbiajuridico.es/news/

El tooltip está en el círculo amarillo pequeño, al poner el cursor sobre él. Si se hace scroll hacia abajo, en las sucesivas páginas el resto de tooltips no se construyen, a pesar de que estoy usando el evento append para construirlos cada vez que se recarga la página.

Aparentemente el código es muy sencillo y no sé qué estoy haciendo mal:

```js
    // TOOLTIPS
    // ------------------

    var miTootip = $('.tooltip-item');
    new Tooltip(miTooltip, {
      // options
    });

    // INFINITE SCROLL
    // ------------------

    var inf = $('.infinite-scroll-container').infiniteScroll({
      // options
    });

    inf.on('append.infiniteScroll', function(event, response, path, items) {
        // ESTA ES LA PARTE QUE NO FUNCIONA
        new Tooltip(miTooltip, {
          // options
        });
      });
```

Agradecería cualquier ayuda para averiguar por qué no funciona el tooltip en las sucesivas páginas (las que se cargan haciendo scroll).

**EDITADO: Al intentar hacer un codepen, me he dado cuenta de que el error está en otra parte. El tooltip sólo aparece en el primer item (no tiene que ver con infinite-scroll). Este es el pen:** https://codepen.io/aitormendez/pen/yRGyZW

Comment: ¿Puedes comprobar que el evento del `append.infiniteScroll` funciona?
Es decir, prueba a realizar un `alert` para comprobar que al realizar un scroll te salta el evento, si es así, el problema será al añadir la ToolTip en los nuevos elementos.

Comment: Sí, lo he hecho con un console log y funciona perfectamente. De todas formas, acabo de descubrir que el error está en otra parte, al intentar construir un codepen, el tooltip sólo aparece en el primer item. Ese es el error y no parece que tenga nada que ver con infinite-scrol. Aquí lo dejo: https://codepen.io/aitormendez/pen/yRGyZW

Comment: No estoy muy segura de ello pero creo que, lo último que mencionas de que el tooltip solo se genera en el primero, es debido a la forma en la que lo generas. Recoges los elementos con clase `infinite-scroll-item` pero solo le asignas el tooltip a uno, el código que genera el tooltip se procesa una única vez y, por lo tanto, solo afecta al primer elemento con dicha clase. Prueba a hacerlo dentro de un bucle por si acaso. (No he probado nada así que no estoy del todo segura)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como dice @Ragebi, estás creando mal los `tooltips`. Tu variable `tt` no contiene un elemento sino un objeto con todos los elementos de la clase `.infinite-scroll-item`. Por ello lo que debes hacer es recorrerlo e ir creando los tooltips individualmente.

```
let tt = $('.infinite-scroll-item');
tt.each(function(){
  new Tooltip(this, {
  title: "Tooltip",
  trigger: "hover",
});
})
```

Te dejo aquí un snippet y el codepen modificado (por si quieres hacerte un fork):

```js
let tt = $('.infinite-scroll-item');
tt.each(function(){
  new Tooltip(this, {
  title: "Tooltip",
  trigger: "hover",
});
})
```

```css
.infinite-scroll-container .infinite-scroll-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 10px;
}

.popper,
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  color: black;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tooltip {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

.popper .popper-arrow,
.tooltip .tooltip-arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 5px;
  border-color: green;
}

.popper[x-placement^="top"],
.tooltip[x-placement^="top"] {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.popper[x-placement^="top"] .popper-arrow,
.tooltip[x-placement^="top"] .tooltip-arrow {
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.popper[x-placement^="bottom"],
.tooltip[x-placement^="bottom"] {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="bottom"] .tooltip-arrow,
.popper[x-placement^="bottom"] .popper-arrow {
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  top: -5px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="right"],
.popper[x-placement^="right"] {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.popper[x-placement^="right"] .popper-arrow,
.tooltip[x-placement^="right"] .tooltip-arrow {
  border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  left: -5px;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.popper[x-placement^="left"],
.tooltip[x-placement^="left"] {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.popper[x-placement^="left"] .popper-arrow,
.tooltip[x-placement^="left"] .tooltip-arrow {
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  right: -5px;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.4/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tooltip.js@1.3.0/dist/umd/tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/infinite-scroll@3/dist/infinite-scroll.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="infinite-scroll-container">
  <a href="#" class="infinite-scroll-item"></a>
  <a href="#" class="infinite-scroll-item"></a>
  <a href="#" class="infinite-scroll-item"></a>
  <a href="#" class="infinite-scroll-item"></a>
  <a href="#" class="infinite-scroll-item"></a>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GYPpvR

Comment: Sí! Eso es. Muchísimas gracias.